# Change the background image "on click" with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I´m new to jQuery and I´m intressred in showing different background image
on click event. Is there any easy way?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please consider read [faq] since you are new :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) on some sort of link/image/button and then [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to switch the image path.

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    $('#image').css("background-image", "url(/myimage.jpg)");
});
```

Answer (score 4):

1.7+

```
$("#id").on("click", function () {
    $(this).css("background-image", "url(/url/to/background/image.jpg)");
});
```

< 1.7

```
$("#id").bind("click", function () {
    $(this).css("background-image", "url(/url/to/background/image.jpg)");
});
```

Comment: I dont see any use of `bind()` and `.on()` on this case. Unless we start like `may be OP wants to do this and that`.

Comment: Don't be pedantic, it's a valid answer.

Comment: Thanx! But the image disappears then the page loads (wordpress)... I tried   with "return false", but the buttn get inactive after the first click then...

Answer (score 0):

Its as simple as this

```
$("#mylink").click(function() { 
           // ^ Attach a function on click event of an element with id="mylink"
  //Change the css of a element with id="myDiv"
  $("#myDiv").css("backgroundImage", "url(newimage.jpg)");
               // Note ^: In jQuery, the parameters with "-" as define that way
               // But of course .css() supports "-" also, but make a habit of doing in camel-case
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/UQGBm/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#your_element").click(function () {
    $("#your_element").css("background-image", "url(" + image_url + ")");
}
```

Replace `#your_element` with the appropriate selector, and `image_url` with a valid url and you're golden.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#divBg").css("background-image", "url(http://www.androidgamespro.com/static/pic7/micky_tap_tap-jazz_jackrabbit-1_010-icon0.png)");
```

Here is the sample : http://jsfiddle.net/aGAha/2/

Answer (score 0):

Reading your Question and knowing that you are new to jQuery, i would like to explain the answer in little more details.

Everybody has given the answers correct in all possible ways.

firstly to access any element on the page you need to select the element using jQuery selectors

all jQuery methods are accessible inside the document.ready function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
//this represents window.load in javascript.

//now to select the element suppose you have anchor tag <a> with id=clickme

$("#clickme").click(function() {

//select the element whose background image you want to change. suppose with id=imgBack
$("#imgBack").css({'background-image':'url(newimage.jpg)'}); 

// Note image can be of any format (.png, .jpg, .gif, etc).
// this way you can change the image. 
})
});
```

for more details in selecting the element with class name you can refer [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) website.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#mylink").click(function() { 
  $('body').css({'background-image':'url(new_image.jpg)'}); 
});
<div id="mylink">Click me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and found a solution using this - https://github.com/rewish/jquery-bgswitcher#readme