# Change background image with fade on click

Tags: jquery, css, onclick, background-image, fade

All of the examples of this concept I have found on here don't do exactly what I need.

I started with this code from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9785708/change-the-background-image-on-click-with-jquery).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#amber").click(function() {
    $(".about-bg").css({'background-image':'url(images/amber.jpg)'}); 
})
});
```

And that got my background images to swap no problem. However, I want to be a bit fancy and have the images fade from one to another. So I altered it to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#amber").click(function() {
    $(".about-bg").hide().css({'background-image':'url(images/amber.jpg)'}).fadeIn(500); 
})
});
```

However, that causes the background images to just switch and my content fades in instead. The options I have found thus far seem to cause the same to occur.

Is what I want possible or do I need to just look into a carousel/slider option?

Edit: Someone marked this as already answered but the posted link isn't for an onclick event and from what I read on the comments that will also fade the content with the image. Maybe I'm wrong because some of this stuff I just can't wrap my head around at times.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a background image can't be faded? Am I wrong?

Comment: If a div has a background image and you fade out the div, the image will be faded out as well...

Comment: to chain animation you should use callback of one to start the second. So for example: `$(".about-bg").hide(function(){$(this).css(...);` will apply the new css while the div is hidden.

Comment: Will that keep the page content from fading in?